# Authentication for asp.net website without using any database

Tags: asp.net, authentication

Is there any way to provide user log-in without the need for a DB.  We are deploying a system to control some hardware and the customer wants an interface they can access from a browser, but they also want to provide log-in to prevent just any body from accessing it.

I have no reason for a DB to implement what I need. I would hate to have to install a DB on the box just to provide authentication.

Pretty sure I am going to use a MVC web project.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick answers. I am a platform developer trying to figure the web stuff out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using forms authentication you can store the credentials in the config file. Check out this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da0adyye.aspx) Link

Answer (score 9):

You can enable authentication via your web config, and specify the users within the same file instead of a database.

An example of this would look like :

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms loginUrl="MyLoginPage.aspx">
    <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
        <user name="Darren" password="foobar" />
    </credentials>
</forms>
</authentication>
```

Then you could use it like

```
 if (FormsAuthentication.Authenticate (txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text)){
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage (txtUserName.Text, False);}
```

see [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210513002246/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/110701-1.3.shtml) for more details

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can use forms authentication and store the usernames and passwords in the web.config.  I wouldn't recommend this approach for anything but the simplest sites.

Have a look at this MSDN article for more info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da0adyye.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Sure. For very simple sites you can simply use [forms authentication](http://www.15seconds.com/Issue/020220.htm) and store usernames/password (encrypted, of course!) in web.config or in a [users.xml](http://authors.aspalliance.com/aspxtreme/webapps/cookieauthenticationusinganxmlusersfile.aspx) file.

For larger, more fully-featured sites you can [implement a custom membership provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx) to use whatever backing store you like, or utilise one of the off-the-shelf ones that are out there (such as [this xml membership provider](http://madskristensen.net/post/XML-membership-provider-for-ASPNET-20.aspx)).

Comment: archived "forms authentication" link: https://web.archive.org/web/20091119230025/http://www.15seconds.com/Issue/020220.htm
archived "users.xml" link: https://web.archive.org/web/20110917144039/http://authors.aspalliance.com/aspxtreme/webapps/cookieauthenticationusinganxmlusersfile.aspx
archived "this xml membership provider" link: https://web.archive.org/web/20100324093257/http://madskristensen.net:80/post/XML-membership-provider-for-ASPNET-20.aspx